# Is it possible to connect paths to objects in Inkscape for a network diagram?

Tags: inkscape, diagrams

I want to be able to move the objects (boxes) around and have the paths stay connected. For a network diagram. Is that possible? I know other tools for this task exist, e.g. [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/variants/) but that does not support exact dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The [diagram connectors tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Connectors-Creating.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) is intended exactly for this.

Comment: Thank you. This works good except for having no horizontal and vertical lines. Is there an option to force lines to be only horizontal and vertical?

Comment: Found it in the upper bar.